# Is there any default defect template available, so that we can fill the sheet and upload to QC directly with all defects by the End of the day

Tags: excel, defect-tracking

We are forced to use HL ALM QC to raise defects. Currently we were using Rally to raise defects for Agile projects. But now on, we need to use HP QC, to raise the defects. For rally, i have created my own template , where i fill the columns with all N number of defects and directly upload in Rally using Addin. So i could save my time in raising the defects all at once. Is there any default defect template available like rally, so that we can fill the sheet and upload to QC directly with all defects by the End of the day.

If so, please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used HL ALM QC but, if it allows users to import bugs from spreadsheets or CSV file, then I'm sure it will also have an option to export existing bugs.

You can export one such bug report and the exported file will then become your default template which you can use for reference.

There is a very good article [here](http://www.guru99.com/hp-alm-defect-management.html) on defect management in HP ALM QC. It also explains about importing issues from files and also has a screenshot of a sample excel sheet which was used to import bugs in their example. You can use this as a reference to make a sample template.

Comment: Great idea.. thanks.. i will try this approach and see if it works and customizing the report